# How to scale jumbotron bootstrap on larger monitors?

Tags: html, css

I currently have a website that uses the jumbotron feature from bootstrap taken from the Codecademy "how to make a website" tutorial.

In it, it uses the following html:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Heading</h1>
            <p>Tagline</p>
            <a href="#About"><button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger">Learn More</button></a>
            <!--<a href="#">Learn More</a>-->
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the following CSS:

```
.jumbotron {
  background-image:url("flight.jpg");
  height: 500px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-bottom:0px;
}

.jumbotron .container {
  position: relative;
  top:100px;
}

.jumbotron h1 {
  color: #CC0000;
  font-size: 48px;  
  font-family: 'Shift', sans-serif;
  text-shadow:none;
}

.jumbotron p {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #CC0000;
  text-shadow:none;
}
```

The background image is not scaling properly when a larger monitor is used, and the image increases in size within the div, but the div stays the same size. The result looks like a zoom on the image rather than the image staying whole.

Any idea how to make it scale properly on larger monitors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change to**

Oh I apologive for misunderstanding your question you need to edit the css for `.jumbotron` needs to be cover and position to center.

```
.jumbotron { background-size: cover; background-position: center;  }
```

**Add Container Div around Jumbotron!**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Heading</h1>
            <p>Tagline</p>
            <a href="#About"><button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger">Learn More</button></a>
            <!--<a href="#">Learn More</a>-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I removed the container div and the issue still occurs. I think it has to do with the picture being stretched by the jumbotron larger than the pictures width. I am still not sure how to fix it though. I put an example up on www.galacticchef.com

Comment: try this...also **add the container back**...you need that to center the content in the jumbotron.

Comment: If I use background-size: contain, the image size stays fixed once the width of the div is larger than the width of the image. This leaves white margins on the left and right on larger monitors.

Is there a way to make the default div height 500px and if the div width is higher than the image size, the div height increases to match the scaled image height?

Comment: The image still scales differently than the div when the width of the div is greater than the width of the image. If I don't have height defined height:500px, the image/div is very small. I tried using different background-position:center and background-position:top.

Comment: @hasanzuav this sounds like what you are trying to do.  Look at my code

Comment: I used background-position:bottom; and it worked. Still some issues with text overlaying the meat of the image but it works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: :) glad it worked out.  Try messing with the padding in the div to make it look right for your text.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE 2:
[This is helpful link.](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) I think, your solution in jQuery.

UPDATE:
Here is solution.

```
background: url("flight.jpg") no-repeat center center;
height: 500px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

You can use `@media` query like this:

```
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      .btn-responsive {
        padding:2px 4px;
        font-size:11px;
        line-height: 1;
        border-radius:3px;
      }
    }

    @media (min-width: 769px) and (max-width: 992px) {
      .btn-responsive {
        padding:4px 9px;
        font-size:12px;
        line-height: 1.2;
      }
    }
```

> With a @media query, you can write different CSS code for different
>   media types.
>
> This helps when you want different layout for different media types
>   such as a screen or a printer, but also when you want different layout
>   for different devices, which is very useful when making web pages with
>   responsive design.
>
> You can also have different layout when a user resizes the browser
>   window up or down to a certain width, or height.

[More info.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Comment: I think the issue happens when the width of the jumbotron div is longer than the width of the image I used. However, since the height of the jumbotron div is fixed, it increases the size of the image at a different rate of the div. There is an example on www.galacticchef.com . Is there a way to make the height of the div 500px and increase when the width is larger than the image size?

Comment: Hi Karmacome, thanks for the help. I tried your updated solution and since it is using background-size:100% when the width of the browser is smaller than the width of the image, the image scales so there is white deadspace between the jumbotron div and the text below (not shown). 
Is there a way to make the default div height 500px and if the div width is higher than the image size, the div height increases to match the scaled image height?